# How compare CodeFunction.Access value?

Tags: function, t4

I'm generating methods of partial classes. Using T4 Text Template

At first, I'm looking for extra implemented methods in the interface.
After that, reading access type, calling CodeFunction.Access.

I need compare CodeFunction.Access result.
I tried:

```
if(extraMethod.Access == vsCMAccessPublic)
if(extraMethod.Access == "vsCMAccessPublic")
```

no result....

If withdraw `<#= extraMethod.Access #>` I get `vsCMAccessPublic`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

```
if(extraMethod.Access ==  EnvDTE.vsCMAccess.vsCMAccessPublic)
```

or

```
if(extraMethod.Access ==  vsCMAccess.vsCMAccessPublic)
```